# Django - In one view, how do I "return render/Httpresponse/etc" to another view?

Tags: python, django

So say I have a view called addPost(like a wall post). It's a model form page for a post object. There are two cases, either the request.method is post, or it isn't. In the case that it's a POST method, I want to return to the profile page after the post is submitted.

I've had this problem a few times, and it usually comes in the form of NoReverseMatch Errors.

How do you "return render/Httpresponse/etc" to another view? in Django? I feel like any solutions I've had before have been really hackish and I want to proper way to implement this sort of feature.

I do want to note that I get this error on myapp/profile.html

Here is the trackback I have:

```
NoReverseMatch at /myapp/profile/1/
Reverse for 'addpost' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/profile/1/
Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'addpost' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 496
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Python Version: 2.7.8
Python Path:    
['/Users/me/project',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-18.0.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 14 Jul 2015 08:12:13 +0000
```

It occurs at this line of code in the html, the button that links to the add_post view.

profile.html

```
{% if user == currUser %}

                  <a href="
      {% url 'addpost' %}
      " class = "btn btn-info"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>


 {% endif %}
```

and it highlights this bit of code in Debug:

```
~/myapp/views.py in profile
                return render_to_response('myapp/profile.html', {'currUser': currUser}, context) ...
▼ Local vars
```

Here are the two views, profile and add_post.

```
@login_required
def profile(request, id):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    currUser = User.objects.get(pk = id)
    profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user = currUser)
    return render_to_response('myapp/profile.html', {'currUser': currUser}, context)

@login_required
@login_required
def add_post(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
    #     #create a form instance and populate it with data from the request
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
             #process data in form.clean_data
            post = Post(user = request.user, title =form.cleaned_data['title'], body=form.cleaned_data['body'])
            post.save()
            return redirect(reverse('myapp/profile', args=[request.user.pk]))


    else:
        form=PostForm()

    return render_to_response('myapp/addpost.html', {'form': form}, context )
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    ...
    url(r'^profile/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
    url(r'^addpost/$', views.add_post, name='add_post'),

)
```

Comment: Redirect to the new view when the post is done.

Comment: just redirect(reverse('profile', args=[request.user.pk])) after the post is successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misdiagnosed the problem. It is nothing to do with redirecting; it occurring in the template itself, because you have used `{% url 'addpost' %}` instead of `{% url 'add_post' %}`.

Comment: Alright I got rid of the error. I had to put {% url 'myapp: add_post %}. Such a dumb mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Just redirect, you don't need to do a `render_to_response`.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

@login_required
def add_post(request):
    ....
    if form.is_valid():
        ....
        return redirect(reverse('profile', args=[request.user.pk]))
```

Comment: It's still not working. I edited and updated my post above for more information. I get the same reverse error.